# how to create a database schema for storing product search filters

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am creating a simple product search webapp where user can filter the shopping products he has bookmarked on the basis of price, free delivery, name, shop etc.

I am looking to implement custom search filters functionality where user can create a search filter, then save it for later use. Search filters are something like this:

- price is under $1000
- price is between $1000 to $2000
- free delivery available/not available
- shop is amazon/walmart/...
- name contains "christmas"

Can somebody give me an idea of the database schema for storing such search filters in database. Should I store the mysql clauses in database like "WHERE price < 1000", "WHERE free_delivery=1"... or may be create fields like this..

- field (price, name, free_delivery)
- value (1000)
- expr (less than, greater than)
- between (1000)
- and (2000)
- contains

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store SQL clauses in the database. I would recommend you do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE store (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Example rows: (1, "Amazon"), (2, "Walmart"), ...

```
CREATE TABLE search_filter (
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
user_id INT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(100),
price_min INT,
price_max INT,
store_id INT,
has_free_delivery BOOLEAN,
keyword VARCHAR(50),
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id),
FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store(id)
);
```

Example row: (1, 43, "amazon christmas", 1000, 1999, 1, True, "christmas")

The above example would save a filter called "amazon christmas" associated with user 43. It specifies that the user wishes to look for products with price ranging from $1000 to $1999 at Walmart, with free delivery, and containing the keyword "christmas."

Comment: Just a note on this answer for this to work you would be required to specify your tables as being INNODB instead of the default value of MyISAM. As can be seen at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html they state "At a later stage, foreign key constraints will be implemented for MyISAM tables as well." this same text has been present for all versions for the last 8 years or so.

Also even if using INNODB you are not guaranteed that the foreign key will be adhered too. MySQL is known to disregard foreign keys at times.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I wasn't aware of that restriction.